# No "Conditional Convergence" in Lebesgue Integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

In my measure theory course, I've heard the professor say numerous times that

**"there is no conditional convergence in Lebesgue integration, it is always absolute."**

As an example, he shared that is it quite easy to prove that Riemann and Lebesgue integrals agree when they both exist, on bounded intervals, yet

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \, dx$$ exists in the sense of Riemann, but does not exist in the sense of Lebesgue as

$$\int_{(0,\infty)} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \, d\mu. $$

"the first accounts for alternation of sign as in an alternating series, while the second does not, and so $f \in \mathcal{R}$ yet $f \notin \mathscr{L}(\mu)$.

Though, I don't understand what is meant by this. What does he mean when he says Lebesgue integration only happens in an absolute sense? Why does Riemann Integration allow for conditional convergence?

Comment: the absoulte is already hidden in the definition of lebesgue integrals $\int f:=\int f^{+}-\int f^{-}$ if both are finite. And both are finite if and only if $\int\left|f\right|$ is finite.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095666/lebesgue-integral-and-absolute-value

Comment: That integral is not a Riemann integral. It is a limit of Riemann integrals. We could similarly define a limit of Lebesgue integrals.

Comment: @zhw. Of course you're absolutely right. Unfortunately people often include "improper" integrals under "Riemann integrals", and hence they say that the Riemann integral of $\sin(t)/t$ _Is_ $\pi/2$, then giving this as an example of something Riemann integrable but not Lebesgue integrable. Totally stupid terminology, it doesn't actually show the R integral integrates something the L integral doesn't, as you point out it's just because that limit is allowed under "R integrable" but not under "L integrable". Alas it _is_ standard usage...

Comment: It is also standard to write $\int_0^{\infty}f(x) d\mu (x)=y$ to mean $\lim_{z\to \infty}\int_0^z f(x) d\mu (x)=y$.